# Is there a way to find and replace any character in a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I am struggling a bit in pandas. How do I find and replace any character in a particular column of a dataframe? 
 For Example, in the below dataframe: 
1. If I want to replace any parentheses with a '-' in column x of the dataframe below or a number in column 'y' with a '-'. 
 2. Another question I have is how to replace everything within the () in column 'x' .
 ie. ('There') is replaced with '-'.

`df=pd.DataFrame(data=({'x':['Hello','(There)'],'y':['R17','R16']}))`

I would be really grateful if someone could help me tell me the code for this and how it works.

Comment: please show more examples, with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here is some example:

```
patern = r'\(|\)|\d+'
df.replace(patern, '-', regex=True)
```

will output

```
>         
x   y
0    Hello  R-
1  -There-  R-
```